# GParted taking forever to complete formatting operation

Tags: gparted, usb-drive

I've been trying to format my USB drive to NTFS so that I can flash windows on it. I used GParted to format the USB, but the operation has been going on for a while now and is not showing any signs of completion. Is something wrong or it usually takes this much time? Please help.

Comment: In a different CLI instance, run `journalctl -b` to display all log entries since your last reboot.

Comment: if you could cancel, simply cancel it. No harm will happen to the USB drive. Then use something like `dd` to write the windows image to the disk. No need to format.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` to perform that operation?

Comment: @GTRONICK GParted always asks for authentication, you can not run GParted without root privileges.

Comment: That's not always true, I have experienced some issues in the past, where gparted did not ask for authentication, and don't work properly. However, this was caused by  broken system, wrong configurations, and conflicting files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To re-initialize a disk drive to be a fresh, empty NTFS file system should take just seconds.

## Warning... this will completely wipe your hard disk. Make sure that you select the correct hard disk!

Start `gparted`. Select the correct disk (ie: /dev/sdb) from the popup selector in the upper-right corner of the interface. Go to the `Device` menu and select `Create Partition Table`. If you're running a UEFI computer, and/or have a hard disk > 1TB, select the GPT partition table. Select the unallocated space on the hard drive. Then go to the `Partition` menu and select `New` and choose NTFS. Done.